# Weather and News Tiles Appear Inactive in the Start Screen

Tags: windows-8

I have seen screenshots of windows 8 start screen where the tile of the weather app displays the actual weather and the tile of the news app displays news ticks. Any google image search for windows 8 will explain what I mean.

Contrary to this, my own start screen displays a pictogram of 'weather' and 'news', but does not display the weather or the news themselves.

[image]

I looked thought some of the options I could find (after all Metro is a novel UI style) but could not find any that will turn this feature on.

Any idea how can I solve this? Can you confirm that the Skype tile should have had some information on it as well?

Answer (score 2):

Right-click on the "News" tile, and select "Turn Live Tile On". Also, make sure that you are connected to the internet.

[image]

As for Skype:

> Can you confirm that the Skype tile should have had some information on it as well?

Not all tiles are live tiles. The Skype tile (at least on my machine) is just a launcher, and does not function as a live tile. However, you are correct that the Weather and News tiles are live tiles.

Comment: I am connected to the internet and this option is already turned on.

Comment: @Artium: That is really strange. If you open the News app, does the app itself work correctly?

Comment: @Mattew Sorry for the previous comment you might have seen (I have deleted it) - The News app does have this option, I did not see it because I accidentally selected two apps at the same time. Still, it was turned on. As for your question, it appears to work correctly to me.

Comment: Is your internet connection set as a metered connection? Metered connections limit live tile updates to 50mb/month, though it's strange that you've never seen an update. See http://www.verboon.info/index.php/2012/10/windows-8metered-connections/ for details. That's the only other thing I can think of.

Comment: Nope, my connection was not metered. Anyway, thanks for trying to help me.